# cannot resolve module 'fs' on edgejs

Tags: node.js, edgejs

i am using latest edgejs(6.5.1) in my node project. but when i use edge in my project,

```
var edge = require('edge');
```

i am getting this error

> cannot resolve module 'fs'

later when i checked the edge.js file i see that edge is using 'fs'

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    builtEdge = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/Release/' + (process.env.EDGE_USE_CORECLR || !fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/Release/edge_nativeclr.node')) ? 'edge_coreclr.node' : 'edge_nativeclr.node')),
    edge;
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Try running `npm i -g fs` on the commandline and try running the project again.

Comment: Holy canole, no. If you're on node and `fs` can't be found, don't install it from npm. That is the _wrong_ solution, always. You have a serious misconfiguration if your node installation doesn't have `fs` since it comes standard. Try updating node to start, and show us the full error message.

Comment: Seconding what @Qix said - all you'll get if you install `fs` from NPM is a [placeholder package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) (to prevent a malicious package from posing as a built-in Node module).